# Disadvantages of forward declaration?

Tags: c++, objective-c, class, forward-declaration, incomplete-type

In C++ and Objective-C, I've gotten into the habit of forward-declaring any necessary classes that do not need to be defined in the header, and then importing the header files defining those classes in source files if needed.

Is there ever a situation in which this wouldn't be a good idea?

(I know the big disadvantage of forward declaration is the limited usability of an incomplete type. For the purpose of this question, assume that in the header I only need to use the forward-declared class as an incomplete type.)

Comment: Less opportunity to drink coffee during a full build?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes you can change the semantics of the program subtly without raising any errors

```
class Foo;

template < typename T>
struct Trait
{
    static const int MY_TYPE = -1;
};

// Lets say this is Foo.h
//class Foo
//{
//};
//template<>
//struct  Trait<Foo>
//{
//  static const int MY_TYPE = 1;
//};

void TestFunction(Foo& f)
{
    std::cout << Trait<Foo>::MY_TYPE << std::endl;
}
```

Consider the above code and the commented out code lives in a header. If the header is included TestFunction will print 1 otherwise -1

Comment: +1 .. Probably more applicable than my comment knowing what I know now about the OP's thought process.

Comment: Interesting stuff. That's the sort of thing I was curious about.

Answer (score 3):

One disadvantage might be the lack of information hiding / encapsulation.

I prefer to have the most minimal header file I can. It means I'm not obligated to continue supporting so many features. If I want to change something, and that something hasn't been exposed in the public header, there is a much better chance I can change it internally to the class without affecting anyone else.

**EDIT:**

Luke asked for an example, so here ya go:

Suppose you have a class called `Car`. And, the only thing you built it for was to get from point A to point B. Me, personally, I'd prefer to keep my header file to: a class called `Car`, and a method called `Drive`. From the way you phrased your question ("all the classes that I can") I would expect to find classes like "DieselEngine", "PetrolEngine", "HybidEngine" and such in your header file as well. The problem with this is that other people working on your project (or, you, over time) start to use those exposed classes. Now, two years later, you decide "Hrm... that PetrolEngine class is really causing problems for me. I think I'm just going to remove it and replace it with the HybridEngine entirely in my Car class" - well, now PetrolEngine is encluded in 100 other files for reasons you don't understand - and now you're forced to keep PetrolEngine around (and working as it used to) for all those other guys who used it in some say you're not really sure of - because you didn't have a solid working "contract" for how you wanted that class to be used in the first place. It was an implementation detail of what you really wanted to accomplish - building a car.

**EDIT to discuss comments about information hiding:**

If all you're doing is strictly forward-declaring the class/struct name - well, I guess I would ask "why" again. If I'm a consumer of your header file and class(es), and I can't actually do anything with that class  - and it's not exposed as a parameter or return type of your principal class's API - then why expose it at all?

If you are using it for compile time type safety checks for opaque data structures - fine - that's one thing. But, the way you phrased your question made it sound to me like *everything* went in the header file as a matter of course.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. Could you give an example?

Comment: Wouldn't this technique enhance information hiding?  There's a lot less information in a forward declaration than in a full declaration.

Comment: Could you explain how forward declarations break encapsulation? It seems to me that providing only the class name hides much more information than providing the full definition.

Comment: @steve I think "all the classes that I can" is ambiguous, I read it as all that i can forward declare rather than #include, did you read it as all I know about I might as well forward declare?

Comment: @morechilli - Yeah I read it as "Hey! Got a class! Better forward-declare!" as like a "rule" he lives by. I could definitely be totally misreading the question.

Comment: @luke what exactly did you mean by "all the classes that I can"?

Comment: Ah, that's my fault. I meant morechilli's interpretation - for any class that needs to be declared, I forward-declare it rather than #include the definition if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Forward declarations can be applied to many things: classes, functions, global variables/constants (using `extern`) and in C++11, enums.

The main disadvantage, as far as I can see, is the redundancy, because redundancy introduces more scope for errors, however this apply very differently depending on what you are forward declaring.

If you have an error with the forward declaration of a class, a global or an enum, the compiler should pick it up (yeah!).

If you have an error with the declaration of a function, then in C++ you've simply created an overload (oups!).

I would therefore say that there is no real disadvantage to forward declaring classes, globals or enums; however when it comes to functions, it's better if you stick to `#include`, you can always create headers grouping the related functions to avoid creating too many files.

Answer (score 0):

None, as far as I know. The only disadvantage, that you already covered, is about using incomplete types. Since you say that there won't be any usages that need fully defined types, you're fine I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declarations are preferred to full file inclusion if you don't need the whole definition of the class in the header. The only disadvantage I can think of was already posted as a comment by @Stephen Darlington which I would give 10 upvotes if I could. :)

Answer (score 0):

One disadvantage is potential memory leak in forward declared types. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1767679/72178) for more details. Microsoft compilers issue `warning C4150: deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'SomeType'; no destructor called` in this case.

Comment: Not a problem with a real compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps mostly a question of readability for your colleagues which will have to continue your coding work.